# Show that $\exists \rho\in (a,b)$ such that $f(\rho)\le f(x)$ forall $ x\in (a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let $f:(a,b)\to \Bbb R$ be lower semicontinuous.
>   Also $\lim_{x\to a+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to b-} f(x)=\infty$.
>   Show that $\exists \rho\in (a,b)$   such that $f(\rho)\le f(x)$ forall $ x\in (a,b)$.

Since $f:(a,b)\to \Bbb R$ is  lower semicontinuous  so if we choose any point $x_0$  in the domain then  given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x_0)-\epsilon\le f(x) $ forall $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$.

Also  $\lim_{x\to a+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to b-} f(x)=\infty$ implies given any $M>0$ there exists $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ such that $x\in (a,a+\delta_1)$, $x\in (b-\delta_2,b)$ implies $f(x)>M$ .

But I am unable to connect everything to obtain the required result.

What should I do? Can someone help?

Comment: if such $\rho$ existed then we would have $f(\rho)>f(\rho)$...something is wrong with the question,or maybe you have a typo

Comment: Surely it should read "$f(\rho) \le f(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$".

Comment: I'm editing the title question to match the ACTUAL question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is growing without boundary at the end points and you defined the function to map to the reals, $f$ needs to be bounded from below, that is to say $\inf_{(a,b)} f =: M > -\infty$. So we have to show that the infimum is actually attained at some point. For this take a sequence $(x_n \in (a,b))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = M.
$$
Now, the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded and so there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ to $x$ (where $x$ cannot be either $a$ or $b$). So we get
$$
f(x)\leq \lim\inf f(x_{n_{k}}) \leq  \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = M,
$$
from which we can read of $f(x) = M$ and hence $x = \rho$.

Hope that makes sense? Also notice that I used a different characterization for the lower semicontinuous via the $\lim \inf $. Are you familiar with it?